# Rearranging differential equation and variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a differential equation in the form $f(y)dx+f(x,y)dy=0$ does it matter which variable is the independent variable. For example can I write it in the form $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{-f(x,y)}{f(y)}$ and have it that $x$ is actually a function of $y$

i.e $x=x(y)$?

Comment: First of all, you need to say exactly what $f(y)dx+f(x,y)dy=0$ means.

Comment: When a differential equation is given in the form M(x,y)đc + N(x,y)dy =0, it does not matter, that is x can be function of y, or y can be a function of y, or both x and y are implicitly related by \Phi(x,y,C)=0.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, but to answer your question.

My first thought it should work as long as the function is bijective. If you have perodic functions such as the sin(x) function, you might end up with some problems when defining x(y)